# jquery - on hover li width id - show the matching id div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="level0">
<li class="level1" id="cat2441"></li>
<li class="level1" id="cat2450"></li>
<li class="level1" id="cat2455"></li>
</ul>

<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2441"></div>
<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2450"></div>
<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2455"></div>
```

Hallo, on hover the li(id) element I would like to show the matching div(id) – and hover an another li (wrong id) or leaving the ul I would like to hide the div

my approach was

```
jQuery('.alles li').mouseover(function() {
    var cat = '"#new-' + this.id + '"';
    jQuery(cat).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using the wrong selectors. Also `'"#new-' + this.id + '"'` this syntax is wrong. There is no need to add those double quotes inside the string.

```js
jQuery('.level0 li').hover(function() {
  var cat = '#new-' + this.id;
  jQuery(cat).show();
}, function() {
  var cat = '#new-' + this.id;
  jQuery(cat).hide();
});
```

```css
.alles-zwei {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level0">
  <li class="level1" id="cat2441">cat2441</li>
  <li class="level1" id="cat2450">cat2450</li>
  <li class="level1" id="cat2455">cat2455</li>
</ul>

<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2441">cat2441</div>
<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2450">cat2450</div>
<div class="alles-zwei" id="new-cat2455">cat2455</div>
```

Comment: Thanks thats it . When hover very fast over the li elements, there is a delay (on display the divs). Can this be fixed?

Comment: @ibu400 if you use `show/hide` instead of `fadeIn/fadeOut` you can change that. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without having to rely on the id of the element just use the class of the two elements. When you select the class it gets returned as an array so you can match the level1 class array with the alles-zwei class array. It will also simplify your HTML code.

```
$('.level1').hover(function(){
    // Gets the index of the current li emement.
    var indx = $(this).index(); 

    // Gets the div element based on the hovered li and hides its siblings.
    $('.alles-zwei').eq(indx).show().siblings('div').hide();
});
```